# Android NavController with Bottom NavBar: how to navigate programmatically?

Tags: android, kotlin

in my main activity, I have a bottom navigation bar that looks like this:
[image]

when switching pages, I only rely on the NavController to switch the fragment in the `FragmentContainerView`, my application do not use any other activity.

---

layout file for `MainActivity`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
        tools:ignore="VisualLintBottomNav"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

kotlin code for `MainActivity`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val navView: BottomNavigationView = binding.navView
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainerView) as NavHostFragment?
        val navController = navHostFragment!!.navController
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    companion object {
        fun navigate(instance : MainActivity, destination : Int, args : Bundle) {
            val navHostFragment = instance.supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainerView) as NavHostFragment?
            val navController = navHostFragment!!.navController
            navController.navigate(destination, args)
        }
    }
}
```

---

clicking on those 4 icons works correctly, but now **I need to navigate programmatically** (with some parameters), in response to user click on something inside some nested fragments, so I wrote the static method `MainActivity.navigate()` to help with that

---

But the problem is, when I navigated to the second page using the `navigate()` method, the fragment changed to the second page, **but the bottom navbar stayed highlighting the first icon**. Then when I click on the 1st (and the 2nd) icon at this time, the fragment won't change anymore. (the 3rd and 4th icon still works, but the 1st and 2nd stays frozen)

Did I use the `navigate()` method correctly? how to prevent the navBar from lagging & freezing like this?

Comment: nevermind, I gave up and resorted to opening another activity instead

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, you should consider the same identifiers for fragments in `mobile_navigation` and menu items in `bottom_nav_menu`.

**bottom_nav_menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:showIn="navigation_view">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home" <-------
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:title="@string/menu_home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage_account" <-------
        android:icon="@drawable/modiriate_hesab_karbari"
        android:title="@string/menu_manage_account" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_user" <-------
        android:icon="@drawable/user"
        android:title="@string/menu_user" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

**mobile_navigation.xml**

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_home" <-------
    android:name="ir.javid.sattar.sample.ui.home.HomeFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_home"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_manage_account"<-------
    android:name="ir.javid.sattar.sample.ui.ManageAcoountFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_manage_account"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_manage_acoount" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_user"<-------
    android:name="ir.javid.sattar.sample.ui.UserFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_user"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_user" />

</navigation>
```

I hope it helps you

Comment: (well I forgot to mention) they are already the same id when I post the question